# Opening and editing ssh C files in Scite?

Tags: c, macos, ssh, terminal, scite

I'm in an intro to scientific programming class right now, and I've been doing the vast majority of my assignments just on the terminal window in my mac. The controls are quite frustrating, and I have been enlightened on using Scite, which I use in the labs. So I downloaded it onto my computer, however, for the life of me I cannot figure out where the files are saved. I can create files in Scite and terminal separately, but I cannot access them on the other editor. How do I create a file in terminal, edit it on scite, and compile it back on terminal? I can do this fine on the computers in the lab, but for some reason I can't do it on my own computer.

Comment: Can you expand on why *File | Save As...* isn't working out for you?

Comment: I'm guessing the terminal window is ssh'd into another machine, where you're doing the compilation/running, but Scite runs locally on your Mac? If so, Scite is reading/writing files on your Mac's local hard disk, but the programs in the terminal window are accessing the disk of whichever machine you're ssh'd into. In which case you may have various options, including (simplest, but least convenient) edit the files locally, then copy them across when you want to run them; mount the remote disk using NFS/sshfs (does OSX support this?); run Scite on the remote machine by have it display locally.